# Using capybara with RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I'm trying to use Capybara with RSpec, but the integration tests are not run when I issue the command `rspec`.

I have followed the instructions on the github page and on some online tutorials. I placed:

```
require 'capybara/rails'
require 'capybara/rspec'
```

In turn in both `rails_helper.rb` and `spec_helper.rb`.
Also, I tried putting my spec which uses Capybara in both `spec/features` and `spec/integration`. However, the specs I wrote are not executed(just as if the file, which is named `currency_views_spec.rb` is ignored).

Comment: I don't think rspec by it self would work, either do a `rspec spec` or use the way I prefer more which is `bin/rake` and it will call internally rspec on the correct files.

Comment: Which version of rspec and capybara do you use ?

Comment: can you try `rake spec` instead of just `rspec` ?

Comment: Do you mark describe as feature? Example, describe "the signin process", :type => :feature do

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add `'require capybara/rspec'` to your `spec_helper.rb file'` to use Capybara together with RSpec.

This is a well-detailed article about [Capybara](https://kolosek.com/rails-capybara-setup/).